# Wide to long data - sort of

Tags: inference, independence

I have data that essentially looks like the following:

```
Patient X1  X2  X3
101     -3  -1  2
102     -5  2   -1
103     1   3   2
,,,
```

I can normalize X1, X2, X3 so that they are all comparable in scale (and they are all measuring outcomes from a specific procedure). So now I have (note these haven't been normalized):

```
Patient X
101     -3
101     -1
101     2
102     -5
103     2
102     -1
103     1
103     3
103     2
```

This is great because now I have more observations and can simplify the results if I
have 50 X variables. Of course, there's no free lunch - the patient-specific observations
are no longer independent. Can I simply add a patient dummy to capture this or is there
any way to salvage this form of the data?

Comment: How you choose to store your data is up to you, but I fail to see any statistical question. You, of course, do not have more or less observations when storing panel data in a long or wide format, just a different representation of the same data.

Comment: Patient-specific observations are not independent in *either* representation. Or, to be more precise, the observations are not independent *regardless of how we choose to represent them*. Dependence is a property of the data generating process, not of the data storage structure.

Comment: You don't have any more observations, really, you have just eliminated the differences among the X variables. I'm not sure why you want to do that, but maybe you have a good reason.   And you already have a patient dummy.   Usually, when we go from wide to long, there is some other dummy to add. E.g. if you have X at time 1, 2 and 3, you can then add a time variable and some software wants data in one format or the other, often depending on the analysis you want to do.

Comment: You lost information: it's essential to include a third field designating *which* version of `X` is involved: `X1`, `X2`, or `X3`.  You might object that no, you can recover this information from the sequence of records, but (a) that violates a basic principle of relational tables, which is that *the sequence of records is undefined* (mathematically a table is a *set* of tuples, not a sequence of them), and (therefore) (b) risks distorting that information if at any later point you (or your software) happen to re-order the physical records in that table.

Comment: Sorry - poorly formed question, I knew that the long/wide thing might throw things off.  This is not about data format.

Comment: I think you simply need to add what type of analysis you want to do after this, e.g. a linear model of the form...

Answer (score 0):

If you exchange the first two rows, you trick yourself into thinking $X_{1, 101}=-1$, which is incorrect. Therefore, you need some additional variable to show the $X$ to which the number corresponds. Then you can exchange the rows without losing information.